# How to idiomatically check that an interface is one of two types in Go

Tags: go, types, interface

Assume that I have a function that accepts a very broad interface, which could wrap(?) or describe many different types such as `int64`, `float64`, `string`, as well as other interfaces. However, this particular function only wants to interact with floats and ints, and will return an error for any other underlying concrete type.

What is an idiomatic way to do this in Go?

Should I use a switch statement and do nothing in the cases where it is `int` or `float64` and return an error in the default case? This seems strange to me because those cases would just be empty.

e.g.

```golang
type BoardInterface interface{
    doThing()
}

type customInt int
type customFloat float64
func (i customInt) doThing() {}
func (f customFloat) doThing() {}
// Other methods for different types here...

func getThing(i BoardInterface) error {

    // i could be string, int, float, customInterface1, customInterface2...
    // but we want to assert that it is int or float.
    switch t := i.(type) {
    case customInt:
        // Do nothing here?
    case customFloat:
        // Do nothing here?
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("Got %v want float or int", t)
    }

    // Do something with i here now that we know
    // it is a float or int.
    i.doThing()

    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally your `BoardInterface` should incorporate all the behavior you want to use `i` for, and that way you can just "interact" with `i` via the methods listed in `BoardInterface`. That way it should not matter what concrete type is wrapped in `i`. If the compiler allowed to pass a value, you have guarantee it implements `BoardInterface`.

If for some reason that is not feasible (or not possible), your proposed solution is fine. You may simplify it by listing all allowed types in a simple `case`, and no need to declare `t`, you may use `i` just as well like this:

```
switch i.(type) {
case customInt, customFloat:
default:
    return fmt.Errorf("Got %T want customInt or customFloat", i)
}
```

(Note I used `%T` in the error message, as that is more informative in this case.)

Comment: Yeah, the toy example I provided is not very accurate, but in my actual use case I definitely need to do something only if it is an int or float. I appreciate your answer, and just wanted to make sure it is not strange to have an empty case. I also like putting them on one line. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the extra tip with `%T`!